# 2 Node Cycles Netrender on totally different machines: Almost the same rendering time?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, network

I've experimented with Blender Net Rendering for the Cycles Renderer these days. For my test setup, I'm using two totally different nodes:

> **Node 1:**
>   Intel Core2Duo (2 Cores, 2 Threads, 2.1 GHz), 4 GB RAM
>   openSuSE 13.1 x64
>   Stats: Linux 3.11.10-7-desktop x86_64 x86_64

**Node 1** combines the Master, one Slave and the Client. Master and Slave are started via command line (no GUI), the Client as GUI of course.

> **Node 2:**
>   Intel Core i5 (4 Cores, 4 Threads, 2.4 GHz), 8 GB RAM
>   Windows 7 64 Bit
>   Stats: Windows 7 AMD64 Intel64 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel

**Node 2** serves as Slave only. The slave is started in the command line without GUI.

I created a short animation and sent it via **Node 1** to the Rendering Cluster. First: It works: Both machines are now rendering with a chunk size of 5. And the results in between are exactly what they are supposed to be.

Now the strange thing comes in: I'm sure that those Nodes have different power and speed, but when I take a look at the details of the job, it appears, that both nodes seem to need nearly the same time to finish a frame:

```
no     status   render time  slave     log          result
1      Done     219.3s       Node2     view log     view result [show]
2      Done     219.3s       Node2     view log     view result [show]
3      Done     219.3s       Node2     view log     view result [show]
4      Done     219.3s       Node2     view log     view result [show]
5      Done     219.3s       Node2     view log     view result [show]
6      Done     221.7s       Node1     view log     view result [show]
7      Done     221.7s       Node1     view log     view result [show]
8      Done     221.7s       Node1     view log     view result [show]
9      Done     221.7s       Node1     view log     view result [show]
10     Done     221.7s       Node1     view log     view result [show]
11     Done     221.8s       Node2     view log     view result [show]
12     Done     221.8s       Node2     view log     view result [show]
13     Done     221.8s       Node2     view log     view result [show]
14     Done     221.8s       Node2     view log     view result [show]
15     Done     221.8s       Node2     view log     view result [show]
16     Done     224.7s       Node1     view log     view result [show]
17     Done     224.7s       Node1     view log     view result [show]
18     Done     224.7s       Node1     view log     view result [show]
19     Done     224.7s       Node1     view log     view result [show]
20     Done     224.7s       Node1     view log     view result [show]
21     Done     218.4s       Node2     view log     view result [show]
22     Done     218.4s       Node2     view log     view result [show]
23     Done     218.4s       Node2     view log     view result [show]
24     Done     218.4s       Node2     view log     view result [show]
25     Done     218.4s       Node2     view log     view result [show]
26     Done     223.3s       Node1     view log     view result [show]
27     Done     223.3s       Node1     view log     view result [show]
28     Done     223.3s       Node1     view log     view result [show]
29     Done     223.3s       Node1     view log     view result [show]
30     Done     223.3s       Node1     view log     view result [show]
```

I already tried to set the Threads configuration on the **Node 2** slave fixed to 4, but the results stay about the same.

Can anyone enlighten me where my mistake is? I don't understand the close equality of the rendering times.